# Will not export a file to alembic?

Tags: export

I bought a monkey model that I need to use in 3DS Max. The only way so far that I have been able to import these terrific models by a Blender animator has been using alembic files (FBX does not work). They are huge (40-100 gb)and also take a lot of work with material unwrapping, but they are worth it.

However, one particular file (out of six that I bought) simply will not export. any ideas? [image]

[[image: 2]

Comment: Now Blender just crashes when I try to export this file.

Comment: I just exported it as an FBX file and it works fine now in MAX. weirdly the other files that exported nicely as alembic files would not export properly as FBX files - they came in deformed. FBX files are preferable since they are 1/100 the size of the alembic files.